# Amazon Cloud EC2 cost

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am going to rent an instance at amazon, for very low usage, probably 10-15 hours per month,  It read 0.5 per hours plus some storage fee and network fee.

just not sure if i am charge a minimum of full 1 month use, or even network traffic which is not from myself ? can someone help further explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged for what you use. If you only use 10-50 hours per month, you'll only be billed for those hours ($0.020/hour) after your free year runs out (assuming your using a micro instance). [Here's a link to the pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Comment: Thx, feel just got cheat by this developer  https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FGB60MK     it just won't work outside US since there is no GPU in the Game Console....